# Llamar a método abstracto desde clase padre en PHP (this, self y static)

Tags: php, self, this, static

¿Como puedo llamar correctamente la implementación de una función abstracta desde la clase padre?. 
El problema es que no termino de comprender `static` y no sé si debería hacerlo con `static` o `$this`.

```
<?php
abstract class ParentClass{
    abstract protected function createArray();

    public function printArray(){
        // ACA LLAMO A MI FUNCIÓN ABSTRACTA
        // OPCIÓN 1
        print_r(static::createArray());
        // OPCIÓN 2
        print_r($this->createArray());
    }
} 

class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    protected function createArray(){
        return [1,2,3,4];
    }
}

$c = new ChildClass();

$c->printArray();
```

**Tengo entendido lo siguiente, pueden corregirme si estoy equivocado.**

`self` : Hace referencia a la misma clase en tiempo de ejecución donde está escrita la palabra, por lo cual, si llamo en mi clase padre la función abstracta con `self` me dará un error, ya que llamará a su definición.

`$this`: Hace referencia a la instancia del objeto, en este caso la instancia ya contará con la implementación del método y por eso funcionará.

Según lo que he leído, `static` preferencia la clase instanciada, en este caso el hijo y por eso funciona.

**¿Alguien puede darme una respuesta simple de que es realmente `static`?**

¿`static` y `$this` son lo mismo? de no ser lo mismo... ¿En que se diferencian?

Finalmente he notado que con `static` se pueden llamar propiedades y métodos estáticos, mientras que con `$this` no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de seguir buscando he llegado a una conclusión más solida de qué es realmente `static`

`static::` hace referencia a los enlaces estáticos tardíos, estos intentan resolver la limitación de `self::` mediante la introducción de una palabra clave (`static`) que hace referencia **a la clase que inicialmente se llamó en tiempo de ejecución**.

> Por otro lado, al ser una mejora de `self` tambien cuenta con la capacidad para acceder a métodos y propiedades estáticas.

En este caso la clase que inicialmente se llamó fue la clase hijo, por lo cual tiene un comportamiento similar a `$this`.

[Leer más sobre Enlaces estáticos tardíos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

Answer (score 0):

Breve explicación `static` y `$this` son completamente diferentes
`static` , `public` `private` o `protected`  son **Modificadores de acceso** ya sea a propiedades o funciones y el `$this` o `self` y `parent` (**Operador de resolución**) hace referencia a la instancia para ejecutar una propiedad o función.

Con respecto a tu pregunta necesitas utilizar `parent` para mandar a llamar la funcion o propiedad de la clase que extiendes tu clase.

[mas información](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)

Comment: No se puede utilizar `parent` en la clase superior (Referenciando al ejemplo de la pregunta). Además me refiero al operador de resolución static, no al modificador de acceso.

Comment: Comentario: static no es modificador de acceso, los únicos modificadores de acceso son public, private y protected

Comment: `static` si es considerado un "modificador de acceso", inclusive en otros lenguajes. Cito: "se permitió usar también el modificador static" [Referencia PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration51.oop.php#migration51.oop-modifiers) -Cito: "En esta página se trata la palabra clave del modificador static" [Referencia de C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static). A pesar de que no especifica la palabra "acceso" y solo "modificador", el contexto si lo hace.